# Why has jQuery apparently stopped working in Firefox 22?

Tags: jquery, linux, firefox, ubuntu, mozilla

So, I am currently running Linux Ubuntu on a Dell laptop, and yesterday Ubuntu ran an update that updated Firefox to version 22.0. Yet, the strangest thing happened... I opened Firefox today, and all of the jQuery code on the webpage I'm making simply stopped working. I'm running Firebug and it threw no errors. And it's not just my website either... I tried going on to StackOverflow (which I am now posting to through using Chrome).. and the entire layout of the site wouldn't even load! Just the text. I went to CodeProject, and certain elements were misaligned and the autosuggest features wouldn't work. Is anybody else having this problem? Any way I can resolve it? At least on my site anyway. It's really annoying because I really like using Firefox because of Firebug's capabilities... Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if any of your add-ons/extensions need to be deactivated? Or check if your Firebug needs an update?
There's a compatibility table here - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Had a similar issue recently with a broken cache. Clearing my cache helped.

Comment: is Javascript turned off?

Comment: @jgb, I gotta say, thank you!! I can't believe it, but clearing my cache actually worked. Not sure what caused the problem, but I'm glad it's fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: Did you rename anything? ...to jquery.js or the like. Instead, keep the filenames as they are (still containing version number) and the browser will not use cached versions. I am not sure what the real cause it, just guessing now.

Answer (score 0):

it may be your firefox profile somehow, try renaming ~/.mozilla/firefox to firefox-old

```
mv ~/.mozilla/firefox{,-old}
```

restart firefox, and browse to your site. if that was the problem you can restore your firefox folder and save your bookmarks and stuff and import it into a new profile.